# Why is LINQ Where search query faster on List<> compared to ConcurrentBag<>

Tags: c#, linq

I have List collection with 100 million entities in it. When I perform a simple Linq `Where()` query, it takes approximately 48 ticks (10,000 ticks = 1ms) for a search, whereas putting 100 million entities in a `ConcurrentBag` and then using the same search query on it takes 58 ticks.

I have repeated the test multiple time and the difference remains pretty much the same.
Can someone elaborate why is there a performance difference?

Comment: Is this really the performance bottleneck in your application? Also, if all collections had identical performance in all situations, we wouldn't have/need multiple collection types. So my question to you is, why do you expect them to perform identically in this situation?

Comment: ConcurrentBag does more things than a List. Why do you think they should have the same performance?

Comment: I'd guess that the thread safety of the `ConcurrentBag` might take a toll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the spec of [`ConcurrentBag<T>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381960.aspx):

> The enumeration represents a moment-in-time snapshot of the contents of the bag. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after GetEnumerator was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the bag.

Internally, `ConcurrentBag` is **creating a new list every time you enumerate over it**, and additional actions.

From [ReferenceSource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs#1dd79ff6a9152ce3):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Short path if the bag is empty
    if (m_headList == null)
        return new List<T>().GetEnumerator(); // empty list

    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        FreezeBag(ref lockTaken);
        return ToList().GetEnumerator();
    }
    finally
    {
        UnfreezeBag(lockTaken);
    }
}

private List<T> ToList()
{
    Contract.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(GlobalListsLock));

    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    ThreadLocalList currentList = m_headList;
    while (currentList != null)
    {
        Node currentNode = currentList.m_head;
        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            list.Add(currentNode.m_value);
            currentNode = currentNode.m_next;
        }
        currentList = currentList.m_nextList;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Naturally, this must be slower than enumerating over a simple list.